# how to play mp3 music files (more than one music) in java?

Tags: java, mp3

I write some core java code to a play one mp3 file in java .I was successful. But i want to play more than one mp3 music file sequentially one by one in java.

can it be possible ??
If possible plz help me.

Here is the demo code ,

```
   import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;

    import javazoom.jl.player.Player;


    public class MP3 extends Thread{
        static int k=0;
        private String filename;
        private Player player; 

        // constructor that takes the name of an MP3 file
        public MP3(String filename) {
            this.filename = filename;
        }

        public void close() { if (player != null) player.close(); }

        // play the MP3 file to the sound card
        public synchronized void play() {
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                player = new Player(bis);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Problem playing file " + filename);
                System.out.println(e);
            }

            // run in new thread to play in background

            new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    try { player.play();}
                    catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e); }
                }
            }.start(); 

        }

        // test client
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String filename = args[0];
            //StringBuffer br= new StringBuffer(filename);
            StringBuffer mp3_name = new StringBuffer();
            String arr[]=new String[3];
            String mp3temp=filename; 
            for(int i=0;i<mp3temp.length();i++) 
            {
            int count = mp3temp.indexOf(",");
            System.out.println(count);
            if(count != -1)
                 {
                    String temp = mp3temp.substring(0,count);
                    System.out.println(temp);
                    mp3_name.append(temp);
                    arr[k++] = temp;
                    mp3temp = mp3temp.substring(count+1,mp3temp.length());
                }
            if(count == -1)
                {
                    if(mp3temp.endsWith("mp3"))
                        {
                            mp3_name.append(mp3temp);
                            arr[k++] = mp3temp;
                            System.out.println(mp3temp);
                            break;
                        }

                }

            }
            StringBuffer bb=mp3_name;
            String test ="";
            String subtest ="";
            for(int s= 0;s < arr.length;s++)
            {

                System.out.println(arr[s]);

            MP3 mp3 = new MP3(arr[s]);
            mp3.play();
            System.out.println(arr[s]);

            // do whatever computation you like, while music plays
            int N = 4000;
            double sum = 0.0;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                    sum += Math.sin(i + j);
                }
            }
            System.out.println(sum);

            // when the computation is done, stop playing it
               mp3.close();

            // play from the beginning
               mp3 = new MP3(arr[s]);
             mp3.play();

            //}
            }

        }

    }
```

Pass mp3 files from comand prompt by separating commas. ex :java MP3 test.mp3,a.mp3,b.mp3

Thanks
Bipin

Comment: have it run the code on your next mp3 file and so on? Will probally need some code to get some answers based on your structure.

Comment: Add a container that holds a list of songs to play, and run through the list while using your code to play each song?

Comment: @ Bipin I editing my answer, I didn't know you were using CMD arguements but my idea should do the trick, maybe with a lil tweaking.

Comment: HI Harper , your below code runs successfully, but it dont allow to play a mp3 file completely.It runs till the for loop ends. Here is the Demo I have written 
 public static void main(String[] args) {       
int length = args.length;
for (int p = 0; p < length; p++) {
Demo mp3 = new Demo(args[p]);
mp3.play();       
// when the computation is done, stop playing it
mp3.close();
// play from the beginning
mp3 = new Demo(args[p]);
 mp3.play();
}
//When done you can print something
System.out.println("All Songs have been played"); 
}

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely possible.

If reading from a directory say your C:\Music, then simple have your program read in all of the locations (I am assuming you are reading in only one at the moment).

Then execute on each of those files by calling your play method(Im assuming you have something similar))

You can loop that method or have it play down the list etc etc.

I can elaborate if you post a snippet of your code.

**EDIT:** I didnt know you were using command line arguements, so I will try and help the best I can.

You should be able to read in each arguement and have it execute on each one until there are not left using a for loop.

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 
           //declare the length of your args
           int length = args.length;
```

Once thats done you can run the play method on each of the songs.

```
       //Perform your loop
       for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        //Call your play method here  
       } // End Loop
        //When done you can print something
        System.out.println("All Songs have been played"); 
       }
```

Comment: Hi Harper , I am sorry for editting ur post. I was trying to edit my post but unfortunatile i edit ur post.plz reply the above demo coding. can u view that demo code.Thanks,Bipin

Comment: Hi Harper , The above code runs successfully. but it can not play the mp3 file till the end . it just load & then goes to 2nd mpe file & so on. can it be possible to play a mp3 till end then it loaded the 2nd one after first mp3 ends.Thanks Harper.

Comment: Yes it should be, I don't know off the top of my head but it seems you just need to add a few more lines or move something around. If I have some time I will try and run something similar and let you know what else I can find out.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what birryree said in his comment. You could change the MP3 class to store a list of filenames. Play can then loop over these playing each in turn.